# What is an Link Table?

Tags: sql, database

I see this term mentioned on some conversations, but I can't find a definition anywhere.

Comment: By "link table" do you mean a table that exists between two tables that established a relationship between them? Look up primary keys and normal form (1NF, 2NF, etc.) for databases.

Comment: Does those tables have a more official name so I can look for information about them? I am trying to figure if they are just normal tables with an specific function (Linking?) or you have to make them specific as "Link table".

I hear it used like this:
"as the relationship is many to many, you would need to create a **_link table_** to reference every author"

Comment: Oh I think I found it.
It would be a "Associative table/entity"?

Comment: Yes, associative entities are related in some way and use "link tables" as a way to associate that data. Just haven't heard the term "link table" before other than as a rough way to describe what its purpose is.

Comment: An alternative name for "associative table":  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity.  I must admit that I thought "junction table" was more commonly used.

Comment: appears that there at least 10 different names for them from this article!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link tables are usually association/bridge tables between different Hub tables in Datavault. They mostly resolve many to many relation between different Hub tables.

Example

Link - INVOICE_LINE_ITEM

Hub - INVOICE, PRODUCT etc.

Here relation b/w INVOICE and PRODUCT are many to many.